# SSL:- expiry date validation of server certificate programmatically Android

Tags: android, ssl, https

In Android application how we can check the expiry date of server certificate during webservice call? I am using version 4 of Android.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's probably too late, but I've found a solution for your problem.
Please check the answers from here [Checking certificates expiration dates in java keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513257/checking-certificates-expiration-dates-in-java-keystore)