# Java - Batch file trying to locate certs that are going to expire using keytool

Tags: java, date, batch-file

I am close on this..  I need to get the date math nailed down and is pretty sloppy right at the moment - I know.  :)

```
REM this is using routines from: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentmath.php

:: Strip the day of the week from the current date
FOR %%A IN (%Date%) DO SET Today=%%A
:: Parse the date, prefix day and month with an extra leading zero
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/-" %%A IN ("%Today%") DO (
    REM For European date format DD-MM-YYYY use SET Day=0%%A and SET Month=0%%B instead
    SET Day=0%%B
    SET Month=0%%A
    SET Year=%%C
)
:: Remove excess leading zeroes
SET Day=%Day:~-2%
SET Month=%Month:~-2%
:: Display the results
SET Day
SET Month
SET Year
:: Convert to Julian date
CALL :JDate %Year% %Month% %Day%
:: Display the result
SET /A sdate=JDate

REM BECAUSE WE ARE POTENTIALLY GOING INTO MULTIPLE KEYSTORES FOR JAVA'S KEYTOOL, WE CAN JUST BY-PASS THE PASSWORD
ECHO.|"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -list -v -alias "company.com" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" > results.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1-15 delims= " %%a IN ('TYPE results.txt ^| FIND "until:" ') DO (
if %%k EQU Jan set mn=01
if %%k EQU Feb set mn=02
if %%k EQU Mar set mn=03
if %%k EQU Apr set mn=04
if %%k EQU May set mn=05
if %%k EQU Jun set mn=06
if %%k EQU Jul set mn=07
if %%k EQU Aug set mn=08
if %%k EQU Sep set mn=09
if %%k EQU Oct set mn=10
if %%k EQU Nov set mn=11
if %%k EQU Dec set mn=12

CALL :Jdatea %%o %mn% %%l
SET /A edate=JDatea
)

Set /A=Result==%eDate%-%sDate%

REM if less than 30 days, send an alert
if %Result% LSS 30 blat -f "sender@company.com" -t "someuser@company.com" -server 1.2.3.4 -subject "certificate for %computername% is about to expire in less than 30 days!" -q


:JDate
:: Convert date to Julian
:: Arguments : YYYY MM DD
:: Returns   : Julian date
::
:: First strip leading zeroes
SET MM=%2
SET DD=%3
IF %MM:~0,1% EQU 0 SET MM=%MM:~1%
IF %DD:~0,1% EQU 0 SET DD=%DD:~1%
::
:: Algorithm based on Fliegel-Van Flandern
:: algorithm from the Astronomical Almanac,
:: provided by Doctor Fenton on the Math Forum
:: (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51907.html),
:: and converted to batch code by Ron Bakowski.
SET /A Month1 = ( %MM% - 14 ) / 12
SET /A Year1  = %1 + 4800
SET /A JDate  = 1461 * ( %Year1% + %Month1% ) / 4 + 367 * ( %MM% - 2 -12 * %Month1% ) / 12 - ( 3 * ( ( %Year1% + %Month1% + 100 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 + %DD% - 32075
SET Month1=
SET Year1=
GOTO:EOF


:JDatea
:: Convert date to Julian
:: Arguments : YYYY MM DD
:: Returns   : Julian date
::
:: First strip leading zeroes
SET MM=%2
SET DD=%3
IF %MM:~0,1% EQU 0 SET MM=%MM:~1%
IF %DD:~0,1% EQU 0 SET DD=%DD:~1%
::
:: Algorithm based on Fliegel-Van Flandern
:: algorithm from the Astronomical Almanac,
:: provided by Doctor Fenton on the Math Forum
:: (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51907.html),
:: and converted to batch code by Ron Bakowski.
SET /A Month1 = ( %MM% - 14 ) / 12
SET /A Year1  = %1 + 4800
SET /A JDate  = 1461 * ( %Year1% + %Month1% ) / 4 + 367 * ( %MM% - 2 -12 * %Month1% ) / 12 - ( 3 * ( ( %Year1% + %Month1% + 100 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 + %DD% - 32075
SET Month1=
SET Year1=
GOTO:EOF


PAUSE
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you run a java program instead? Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513257/checking-certificates-expiration-dates-in-java-keystore

Comment: As much as I would like to run a Java Program, I stayed with the Keytool and have sorted out how to do it with Keytool and have answered my own post.

Comment: please post your answer as an answer and accept it, so this question is removed from the "open questions" queue.

Comment: @Stephan - Done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER:** I have figured this out..

There was some commentary to create/use a Java program file to do this, but this will work fine.

```
REM ROUTINES ARE FROM: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/datediff_nt.txt
SET DEST=D:\WORK\SCRIPTS\results.txt

REM BECAUSE WE ARE POTENTIALLY GOING INTO MULTIPLE KEYSTORES FOR JAVA'S KEYTOOL, WE CAN JUST BY-PASS THE PASSWORD
ECHO.|"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -list -v -alias "Some-Alias" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" > %DEST% && SET alias="Some-Alias" && CALL :datecheck
ECHO.|"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -list -v -alias "someother" -keystore "C:\anotherfolder\keystore.ks" > %DEST% && SET alias="someother" && CALL :datecheck

:datecheck
FOR /F "tokens=11-15 delims= " %%a IN ('TYPE %DEST%^| FINDSTR "until:"') DO (
  IF %%a EQU Jan SET eDate=01/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Feb SET eDate=02/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Mar SET eDate=03/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Apr SET eDate=04/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU May SET eDate=05/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Jun SET eDate=06/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Jul SET eDate=07/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Aug SET eDate=08/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Sep SET eDate=09/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Oct SET eDate=10/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Nov SET eDate=11/%%b/%%e
  IF %%a EQU Dec SET eDate=12/%%b/%%e
)

CALL :ParseDate %eDate%
REM CALL :ParseDate 05/27/2017

REM :: Parse the first date
REM CALL :ParseDate %1

:: Convert the parsed Gregorian date to Julian
CALL :JDate %GYear% %GMonth% %GDay%

:: Save the resulting Julian date
SET JDate1=%JDate%

:: Use today if no second date was specified
IF "%~2"=="" (
    FOR %%A IN (%Date%) DO SET Date2=%%A
) ELSE (
    SET Date2=%2
)

:: Parse the second date
CALL :ParseDate %Date2%

:: Convert the parsed Gregorian date to Julian
CALL :JDate %GYear% %GMonth% %GDay%

:: Calculate the absolute value of the difference in days
IF %JDate% GTR %JDate1% (
    SET /A DateDiff = %JDate% - %JDate1%
) ELSE (
    SET /A DateDiff = %JDate1% - %JDate%
)

:: Format output for singular or plural
SET Days=days
IF %DateDiff% EQU 1 SET Days=day

:: Prefix value with a minus sign if negative
IF %JDate% GTR %JDate1% SET DateDiff=-%DateDiff%

:: Display the result
ECHO First date  : %1
ECHO Second date : %Date2%
ECHO Difference  : %DateDiff% %Days%

IF %DateDiff% LSS 30 D:\WORK\SCRIPTS\Blat.exe -server 1.2.3.4-to user@company.com -f sender@company.com -s "Certficiate is to expire in less than 30 days" -body "Certficiate is to expire in less than %DateDiff% days for %COMPUTERNAME% for %alias%" -q

:: Return the result in a variable named after this batch file
ENDLOCAL & SET %~n0=%DateDiff%
GOTO:EOF


::===================================::
::                                   ::
::   -   S u b r o u t i n e s   -   ::
::                                   ::
::===================================::


:JDate
:: Convert date to Julian
:: Arguments : YYYY MM DD
:: Returns   : Julian date
::
:: First strip leading zeroes; a logical error in this
:: routine was corrected with help from Alexander Shapiro
SET MM=%2
SET DD=%3
IF 1%MM% LSS 110 SET MM=%MM:~1%
IF 1%DD% LSS 110 SET DD=%DD:~1%
::
:: Algorithm based on Fliegel-Van Flandern
:: algorithm from the Astronomical Almanac,
:: provided by Doctor Fenton on the Math Forum
:: (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51907.html),
:: and converted to batch code by Ron Bakowski.
SET /A Month1 = ( %MM% - 14 ) / 12
SET /A Year1  = %1 + 4800
SET /A JDate  = 1461 * ( %Year1% + %Month1% ) / 4 + 367 * ( %MM% - 2 -12 * %Month1% ) / 12 - ( 3 * ( ( %Year1% + %Month1% + 100 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 + %DD% - 32075
FOR %%A IN (Month1 Year1) DO SET %%A=
GOTO:EOF 


:ParseDate
:: Parse (Gregorian) date depending on registry's date format settings
:: Argument : Gregorian date in local date format,
:: Requires : sDate (local date separator), iDate (local date format number)
:: Returns  : GYear (4-digit year), GMonth (2-digit month), GDay (2-digit day)
::
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ('ECHO.%1') DO (
    SET GYear=%%C
    SET GMonth=%%A
    SET GDay=%%B
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Thanks